# Event capturing not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying things with events capturing in JavaScript and it's not working as expected.

For example, here is some html :

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="someimage.jpg"><img src="someimage.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

and JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
}, true);
```

My understanding is that since capturing is set to `true`, clicking the image should log `DIV` to the console. Instead, it logs `IMG`...

If someone could explain why, or point to a doc that explains it, it would be great.

Comment: Because you explicitly said `event.target`? If you replace it by `this` you will get `DIV`... you can think `event.target` as being the element right in front your cursor when clicking

Comment: it works, i can't believe it was so simple... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confusing the *element handler* with the *element target*.

When you use `event.target` you are referring to the element right in front your cursor when clicking.

Instead, to refer to the element handler of the event you should use the keyword `this`.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that since capturing is set to `true`, clicking the image should log `DIV` to the console. Instead, it logs `IMG`...

That's simply wrong. `event.target` will always return the element the event was triggered on, independently of the event handling phase. See the [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event).